# Flutter 3.13.5 option --mode=null-safety not available with dart pub outdated

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to upgrade a project to null safety.
I use flutter SDK 3.13.5.
Dart SDK version: 3.1.2 (stable) (Tue Sep 12 16:26:23 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"
When I execute the command

```
> dart pub upgrade --mode=null-safety
```

I got this error:

```
Could not find an option named "mode".

Usage: dart pub upgrade [dependencies...]
-h, --help               Print this usage information.
    --[no-]offline       Use cached packages instead of accessing the network.
-n, --dry-run            Report what dependencies would change but don't change any.
    --[no-]precompile    Precompile executables in immediate dependencies.
    --major-versions     Upgrades packages to their latest resolvable versions, and updates pubspec.yaml.
-C, --directory=<dir>    Run this in the directory <dir>.
```

The documentation is not up to date https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-upgrade (null-safety available...)

Also tried

```
> dart pub upgrade --null-safety
```

but indicate 'is no longer supported'.
How to do? (without this option, it upgrade to the latest version)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you are using an older version of `Flutter (3.13.5)`, and the  `--mode=null-safety` option is not available in that version. The `--mode=null-safety` option is used in earlier versions of the Dart SDK before the official null safety support was introduced.
run those commands, and i hope it will help you to resolve your issue:

`dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`

If any of your dependencies are not null-safe, you will need to update them to null-safe versions.

Once all of your dependencies are null-safe, run:

`dart pub upgrade`

This will upgrade all of your dependencies to their latest versions, and it will also enable null safety in your project.

Comment: "you are using an older version of Flutter (3.13.5)" . THat's actually the newest

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I saw in the console that i need dart 2.19.
So I went to https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows and took flutter sdk 3.7.12 that have le latest dart 2.19.x.
Command are now available.
Hop it helps.